# how i can remove lagging in my unity android game?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am adroid proggrammer,because of many object in scene my game has lagging
i have theory for remove lagging in my game.
if i can control rendering in unity i can remove lagging.
[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
        void Update(){
    void Start(){
        GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }
            object2 = GameObject.Find("TR");
            var distance = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, object2.transform.position);
            print (distance);
            if(distance <= 80){
            GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't work.how can i have boolean render that when have collision will render
else remove.
i want have zone that all object in my zone rendered and allthing outside do not render.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "zone")
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        }
else{
               GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
}
```

don't work

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "zone")
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
else{
               gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is either implemented in Unity or implementing it is a bad idea because raycasts are expensive and you need a lot of them. Try finding other problems which cause lagging in your game, disable feature by feature and write how many frames you have, this will get you best overview of what's the problem. Look online which methods are expensive (Instantiating, Destroy, try merging all models you have, smaller amount of shaders, fast shaders, less textures to load, FindGameObjectByName (or tag...)).

Comment: This may not help much but its good to remember that compare tags like this `gameObject.CompareTag("tag")` not with == operator.

Comment: It all depends on how many times you run that code, see what you run most and try to optimize it as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a great document about optimization. It's preapared for mobile devices but i hope you will find what you need: [Unity Optimization Guide for x86 Android](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/542152)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having your blue blobs in an object pool, and the ones leaving your screen getting disabled.

You know your position and you know the position of the objects in the pool, you can math your distance in one direction, for instance behind you and disable after x amount.
Raycasting or collisions are abundant.

On your terrain generation scripts, check for disabled pool objects and if one exist, it should be put ahead in the level and repositioned or w/e logic you have there.

Don't instantiate and destroy unless you really need it, do it on level-load instead of on the fly.
(It's expensive.)

There's some really good tutorials on the unity page, have a look there.
They cover things like endless-runners.